# Why does the query not return results after I switch the class it queries?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Parse.com and JavaScript SDK.

UPDATED from answer below

```
function friendFeed() {
    friendName = $('#friendsearch').val();
    console.log(friendName);
    var query = new Parse.Query(myBadges);

new Parse.Query("myBadges").matchesQuery("username", new Parse.Query("_User").equalTo("username", friendName))

    query.find({
```

Right this makes no sense! the below code works as expected below and returns a user when I use the _User class in the variable "myBadges" BUT

if I swap this for the class myBadges which contains a pointer to _User no results are returned

I don't understand why that would be happening?

```
var friendName;
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var myBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");


// Captures the input from the user and checks if the name already exists within the Db.
function findFriend() {
    friendName = $('#friendsearch').val();
    console.log(friendName);
    var query = new Parse.Query(myBadges);
    //query.include("BadgeName");
    //ery.include('mtBadgesPOINTER');
    query.equalTo("username", friendName); // find users that match

    query.find({
        success: function (friendMatches) {

            $('#imgs').empty();
            $('#no_user').hide();
            // This section is always run, no matter the outcome. Depending on the input depends on which result is shown
            console.log(friendMatches);
            if (friendMatches.length === 0)
                $('#no_user').show();
            console.log('NO MATCH FOUND!!!')

        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('Opps we have a problem' + error.message);
        }
    });

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$('#find_button').click(function (e) {
    findFriend();
});

< /script>
<div id="imgs"></div >
    < img style = "display:none"
src = "/img/no-user.png"
id = "no_user"
alt = "No user found" >
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it's supposed to work. Because you've established a pointer to User from myBadges you need to query using a pointer as well. Pass the string value of the username doesn't work because the string doesn't equal the pointer.

If you're using the username to look up badges, you'd need a query along this line:

```
new Parse.Query("myBadges").matchesQuery("username", new Parse.Query("_User").equalTo("username", friendName))
```

Which uses compound queries to find users matching the given `username` and then `myBadges` where the user equals a result from the first query.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with your comments, is that in line with what you meant? Also this returns all badges no matter what user is selected. For example "Dave" returns 4 badges back, but it should only be two. How would I only select the badges that the user has actually uloaded? would that be a further Equal to query on myBadges ? http://kudosoo.com/friendslist.html

Comment: is the updated code in the question what you meant? as the filter does not seem to work still

Comment: I think you answered this, but I've continued the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874834/why-is-incorrect-data-being-returned-from-query-runs?noredirect=1#comment36750894_23874834