# Why does this query return all query results and not just those matched with users name?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

UPDATE - The bounty is to help me resolve this issue and allow the code to filter back query results based on the user input. Full code can be shared if it helps via [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

I can't understand why the script below is returning all results to the user when it should only return the results from the "myBadges" class that have been uploaded by "friendName".

Maybe its something to still do with pointers using the objectId and not the actual name "dave" associated to the?

http://www.kudosoo.com/friendslist.html

Still stuck on this. Following my orignal question from:
[Why does the query not return results after I switch the class it queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842425/why-does-the-query-not-return-results-after-i-switch-the-class-it-queries/23851296?noredirect=1#23851296)

```
<script?
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.username', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        friendName = $(this).text();
        console.log(friendName);
        friendFeed();
    });
});


var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var myBadges = Parse.Object.extend("myBadges");

// Captures the input from the user and checks if the name already exists within the Db.
function friendFeed() {
    var friendName = $('#friendsearch').val();
    console.log(friendName);
    var query = new Parse.Query(myBadges);

    new Parse.Query("myBadges").matchesQuery("uploadedBy", new Parse.Query("_User").equalTo("username", friendName));
    query.find({
        success: function (rules) {

            imageURLs = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                var object = rules[i];
                imageURLs.push(object.get("BadgeName"));
                username.push(object.get("uploadedBy"));
            }

            for (var j = 0; j < imageURLs.length; j++) {
                $('#FriendsStuff').append("<img class='images' src='" + imageURLs[j] + "'/>");
                $('#FriendsStuffName').append("<div class='username'>'" + Username[j] + "'</div>");
            }

        },
        error: function (error) {
            //If the query is unsuccessful, report any errors
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }

    });
}

</script>
<div id="imgs"></div>
<div id="username"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="FriendsStuff"></div>
<div id="FriendsStuffName"></div>
```

[image: Here is the console.]
[image]

Comment: "Full code can be shared if it helps via jfiddle" A jsFiddle Always helps!

Comment: First, you jsfiddle is wrong say $(document).on('click', '.username', function (event) { but there are no element with username class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code states:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(myBadges);
new Parse
      .Query("myBadges")
         .matchesQuery("uploadedBy", new Parse.Query("_User")
                                            .equalTo("username", friendName)
                      );
```

It does not assign the correct object to `query`.

I believe it should be

```
var query = new Parse
                  .Query(myBadges)
                    .matchesQuery("uploadedBy", 
                                  new Parse.Query("_User")
                                        .equalTo("username", friendName)
                                 );
```

### Update:

Other problems show up here, with the `friendName` variable.

This is declared inside your `friendFeed` function:

```
function friendFeed() {
    var friendName = $('#friendsearch').val();
    ...
}
```

In this way, it is not accessible outside the function. Plus, you set a value here, but try to overwrite it on your event.

Prefer a parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.username', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        friendFeed($(this).text());
    });
});

function friendFeed(friendName) {
    //var friendName = $('#friendsearch').val();
    ...
}
```

Comment: So remove  var query = new Parse.Query(myBadges); completely and just use the above line you suggested? Even if I do that no results are returned when filtering on a user that should have some. Any further ideas?

Comment: @Dano007 or rather `query = new Parse.Query(myBadges).matchesQuery("uploadedBy", new Parse.Query("_User").equalTo("username", friendName));`? (without quotes on myBadges)

Comment: @GôTô in your last comment you meant exlcude the "var" as per your original answer? I've got this code in a online code editor I can give you temp access to if thats easier? (As per your last comment, it still was'nt working ;-/)

Comment: @Dano007 no I meant "remove the quotes on myBadges" ie `Query("myBadges")` ==> `Query(myBadges)`. The var was unintentionnally forgotten

Comment: @GôTô ok, adjusted as suggested, still no luck. I've added a screen shot of the parse.com backend. Does that help. Happy to give you access to the actual online code if that helps?

Comment: @Dano007 The creation of the jsFiddle was unsuccessful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54637/discussion-between-dano007-and-goto).

Comment: @GôTô many thanks, I need to wait 22 hours before awarding the bounty so will do asap.

Comment: @GôTô as per your Jfiddle, the only bit I dont see how its working is for the within the html that displays the images after username is clicked. I wanted the user to click on the badge name and for it to respond in te same way as if they selected a nmae from the search and click "find" I'd imagine its a tweak I need to make to the receiving divs <div id="FriendsStuff"></div>
<div id="FriendsStuffName"></div>    ?

Comment: @Dano007 I answered in the chat, let's continue there when you have other questions